# VS Code Java problems

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have had this very annoying problem with my java project in VS Code.

My project is the folder project, and in it there is resources folder, src folder and some other files. in src I have some packages and in them I have my java code.

My java code is packaged as not in src i.e. the first line is:

```
package foo.bar.baz;
```

And not:

```
package src.foo.bar.baz;
```

And for some mindbending reason, VS Code cannot understand that it needs to run from within the src folder and it sends me a message to add project/src/foo/bar/baz/code.java to the path which is not what I want. I can skip it or apply it and if I skip it it doesn't run.

Even when I'm editing that settings.json source path to be the right one it doesn't go.

I cannot change the project's structure in any way and I am using the regular java extension pack with nothing else added.

I would love some help because it seems to happen randomly over project with similar structure.

Thanks!

Comment: "it needs to run from within the src folder". .java files can't be run, they can be compiled, and the result can be run, but they won't be in the src folder. Just because your directory is called src, doesn't mean it's a source directory, that might be your problem

Answer (score 1):

Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**. After that, right click the folder src and click **Add Folder to Java Source Path**, which is equivalent to add the following code in Settings.json:

```
"java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src"
    ],
```

Then the code should work without errors:
[image]

Comment: @eliavo. May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If solved, please [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it as answer. If not, please share it here. We can work together to figure it out.